# Rails 3 current_page unexpected behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-helper

I don't what to think...
In routes.rb I have a route:

```
match 'profile' => 'profile#index', :via => :get
```

I am in the `/profile` action.

params.inspect gives me **{"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"profile"}**

I don't know Why Doed **current_page?(:controller => 'profile', :action => "index" )** give **false**?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
current_page?(profile_path)
```

It's always better to use the url helpers rather than specifying controllers and actions in your code.

Comment: Tnanks for help. But **current_page?(profile_path)** returns false too.